# How do I use JGit for Pulling or Fetching?

Tags: java, git, fetch, pull, jgit

I had seen other similar questions but not a functional code that fetchs or pulls using JGit. Could anyone help me with a  small pulling example or explanation that doesn't throws a JGIT Pull NoHeadException.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about adding the code you tried which does not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can see examples in JGit Cookbooks:

- [`FetchRemoteCommits.java`](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/f01714f1fda6cafad9850194d76c182508702907/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/FetchRemoteCommits.java)

That is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GitAPIException {
    try (Repository repository = CookbookHelper.openJGitCookbookRepository()) {
        System.out.println("Starting fetch");
        try (Git git = new Git(repository)) {
            FetchResult result = git.fetch().setCheckFetchedObjects(true).call();
            System.out.println("Messages: " + result.getMessages());
        }
    }
}
```

- [`PullRemoteRepository.java`](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/e5d63f02670de5971564e964e76dde9b42a3cac6/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/unfinished/PullRemoteRepository.java)

That is:

```
try (Git git = new Git(repository)) {
    PullResult call = git.pull().call();
    System.out.println("Pulled from the remote repository: " + call);
 }
```